# Using Constructor in Solidity

Tags: erc-20

How can I use constructor in the following solidity codes.

```
    pragma solidity 0.4.24;


    contract owned {
        address public owner;

        function owned() public {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }

        modifier onlyOwner {
            require(msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }

        function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
            owner = newOwner;
        }
    }
*****************************************************************

    contract TokenERC20 {
        string public name;
        string public symbol;
        uint8 public decimals = 18;
        uint256 public totalSupply;

    function TokenERC20(
            uint256 initialSupply,
            string tokenName,
            string tokenSymbol
        ) public {
            totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;               
            name = tokenName;                                  
            symbol = tokenSymbol;                               
        }
    ****************************************************************

    contract MyAdvancedToken is TokenERC20, owned{

    function MyAdvancedToken(
            uint256 initialSupply,
            string tokenName,
            string tokenSymbol
        ) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}
    _____________________________________________________________
```

Is the following coding a right way to use constructor for the codes mentioned above?

```
    pragma solidity 0.4.24;

    contract owned {
        address public owner;
        address public newowner;

        event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);


        constructor() public {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }

        modifier onlyOwner {
            require(msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }

        function transferOwnership(address _newowner) public onlyowner {
            newowner = _newowner;
        }
        function acceptOwnership() public {
            require(msg.sender == newowner);
            emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newowner);
            owner = newowner;
            newowner = address(0);   //Why address 0x0 is used here??
        }
    }

    ********************************************************

    contract TokenERC20 {

        string public name;
        string public symbol;
        uint8 public decimals = 18;
        uint256 public totalSupply;

    constructor() public {

        totalSupply = 750 * 10 ** uint256(decimals); 
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;              
        name = "MyAdvancedToken";                                 
        symbol = "MAT";

    *************************************************************                              

    contract MyAdvancedToken is TokenERC20, owned {

    constructor()
        TokenERC20 public {}

    ______________________________________________________________
```

I deeply appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to OpenZeppelin sample code to understand more about `constructor` of smart contract

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol

Answer (score 0):

As you may know 0.4.24 deprecate the use of “same-name-of-contract” function to implement the constructor. Given this,
all is as it was before!
Do simply substitute the same-name-function-name using the reserved word “constructor”. Nothing more is required for this.

(BTW The precautional use of the pragma experimental 0.5.0 as well is highly recommendable when using 0.4.24 in the developing phase!)